# use magento rest api to manage attribute sets

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, api, rest-api

i want to manage attribute sets of magento using rest api like i use to manage products (insert, update and delete). The resources in the rest api documentation http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/resources.html are only for products, orders and customers. This can be achieved using the magento SOAP api but i want to do it using the rest api. Do i have to implement it myself or there is another way? please help!

Comment: I would say if it is not documented you can look in the source. But I would assume you have to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no REST api available for attribute sets (or attributes).
If you take a look at the Api2 folder inside the Mage_Catalog module you will see only files related to products ...so I guess you have to code it yourself.

If you do, please post the code somewhere. This should be a valuable resource for others also.